# Click in a shape WinForm

Tags: c#, winforms

I am drawing a circle of `_radius = 50` pixels in the center of the form:

```
g.FillEllipse(Brushes.Red, this.ClientRectangle.Width / 2 - _radius / 2, this.ClientRectangle.Height / 2 - _radius / 2, _radius, _radius);
```

Now I want to check if the user clicked in the form.

```
if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
{
    int w = this.ClientRectangle.Width;
    int h = this.ClientRectangle.Height;

    double distance = Math.Sqrt((w/2 - e.Location.X) ^ 2 + (h/2 - e.Location.Y) ^ 2);
    ....

 if (distance <_radius)
    return true;
 else
    return false;
}
```

Now I am ending up with wrong values. For instance if I click on the edge of the circle I at times get distance of ~10 or NaN at times. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The ^ operator does not do what you think it does, use Math.Pow().  And in general don't do it this way, you'll like GraphicsPath.  Both to draw and to hit-test with its IsVisible() method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You're performing integer division, which is coarser than floating-point division.
2. `^` is not the "power-to" operator, [it's the bitwise XOR operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/xor-operator), which is probably not what you want. Use `Math.Pow` or `x*x` instead.
3. You can simplify the last statement by simply doing `return distance < _radius`.

Try this:

```
Single w = this.ClientRectangle.Width;
Single h = this.ClientRectangle.Height;

Single distanceX = w / 2f - e.Location.X;
Single distanceY = h / 2f - e.Location.Y;

Single distance = Math.Sqrt( distanceX  * distanceX + distanceY * distanceY );

return distance < this._radius;
```

(This code does not change any assumptions about the location of the circle).

Comment: The above code gives me a distance of 50 for radius 100, when I click on the surface of the circle. Am I missing something simple here?

Comment: @SanjnaMalpani Is `e.Location.X` and `.Y` relative to the top-left corner of the circle, or of the form, or something else?

Comment: Sorry, stupid me. I am getting confused between radius and diameter. Works well, thank you